# SonicWALL dedicated link between

Tags: vlan, sonicwall

I have a little problem with two SonicWALLs connected between each other with a dedicated link in layer 2 from our ISP.

Let's call them SonicWALLs A and B. From SonicWALL A, the connection is done with a VLAN in the port X4:110, with the IP address 10.20.0.254 (encap dot1q). From SonicWALL B, the connection is from a physical port without dot1q. Is this the reason SonicWALL B is not able to ping the IP address from SonicWALL A?

This is a possible cause, because I have knowledge from Cisco, but my point of view, this is not able to communicate.

Another question: I created two static routes from both SonicWALLs 
with LANs connected to them, and traffic from SonicWALL A's LAN is able to ping. On the other hand, traffic from SonicWALL B's LAN is not able to ping.

I believe this is because of the encapsulation. Can someone confirm if this is the problem?

These are the statistics from both rules in SonicWALL B:

LAN A TO LAN B

On the other hand, the rule in reverse flow shows Rx statistics flowing well.

```
#14 LAN > LAN 14 Change priority... 130.0.10.0 X0 Subnet Any Allow All None Enabled Enabled
Access Rule #14 - Traffic Statistics
Rx Bytes: 1000285
Rx Packets: 3744
Tx Bytes: 298962
Tx Packets: 3377
Usage: 451
LAN B TO LAN A
```

These are the statistics, but it didn't work, the Rx bytes are still in 0.

```
#LAN > LAN 13 Change priority... X0 Subnet 130.0.10.0 Any Allow All
Access Rule #13 - Traffic Statistics
Rx Bytes: 0
Rx Packets: 0
Tx Bytes: 41760
Tx Packets: 696
Usage: 2
```

Comment: Are you trunking to the ISP, or is this a direct link? Either way, I'm guessing you need to configure A to have the same VLAN info as B. Another thing, what's the IP address on B-X4? Are router A-X4 and B-X4 in the same network prefix?

Comment: Hello  stevieb thanks for the reply, is a dedicated link in Sonicwall B the ip address for the interface is the 10.20.0.1 but doesn't have a vlan tag or dot1q, i believe, and from the Sonicwall A the ip address is 10.20.0.254 /24 and i can ping the ip address 10.20.0.1 from Sonicwall B but not in the other way, could that be the possible cause??

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that you have VLAN tagging mismatch between the two SonicWALLs.

How are they connected? With a switch? Or some other device? (an ISP's MPLS device of some kind?)
**Note:** *I am going to assume on SonicWALL B that the interface is X3, since you don't state it -- just so things are clear. Your packet counts are for X0.*

If *SonicWALL A* has:

```
X4:110
```

then that is a VLAN subinterface, it will be sending TAGGED VLAN packets out tagged on VLAN 110. Whatever interface/IP you have on **X4** will be UNTAGGED.

If *SonicWALL B* has:

```
X3
```

Then that is a regular interface, it is expecting only UNTAGGED packets.

If they are connected by a switch then configure the port for SonicWALL A's X4 interface as TAGGED on VLAN 110, and the port for SonicWALL B's X3 interface as UNTAGGED on VLAN 110. OR create a VLAN subinterface on SonicWALL B with the same VLAN ID (eg. X3:110).

Likely you making SonicWALL B's X3 speak to SonicWALL A's X4, not SonicWALL A's X4:110.

*You need both sides to agree*: tagged or untagged packets. A switch can add/remove tags based on the Port VLAN IDs and VLAN membership settings; or the SonicWALL ports need to be set the same.